# A mechanical system with coupled oscillators and dampers

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, vibration, springs

I found here [Coupled oscillators](http://www.sharetechnote.com/html/DE_Modeling_Example_SpringMass.html), the last one on this page, a system named by the author "Vehicle Suspension System". But I am not sure this modelizes a suspension for a vehicle.

I am interested to find and describe appropiate physical phenomena modelized by mechanical systems of this type and any other bibliographical references would be of help. Is it somehow related to a vibration reduction system in civil engineering?

Comment: Systems like this could be for civil applications, but more typically are for very traditional mechanical engineering systems.  The example you show is purely for academic use.  But you need to be more clear what you are looking for.  Are you trying to model automobile suspension?  Try googling automobile suspension vibration models.  Vibrations is a 4000 level ME class & uses differential equations, don't expect this to be easy.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have already studied the dynamics of this system by solving the corresponding system of second-order ODEs and I am interested to describe physical phenomena which could be modelized by it.
I'm confused about that horizontal wall at the top. If it is fixed and we discuss about a suspension of a vehicle, what could the horizontal wall actually represent? In this case, can the block m_1 be considered as the seat and m_2 as the wheel? Or, in the case it would modelize a vibration reduction in civil engineering, how can I describe it? What would the blocks represent?

Comment: Could you provide references for traditional mechanical engineering systems which are close to this one?

Comment: @chris, the wall would be the road.  I'm not sure what you're looking for.  The shown example looks to me to simply be an exercise example.  The blocks don't represent anything except something you can solve a problem about.